# How to know witch value to display Introductory Price or normal Price for an Apple subcription

Tags: ios, app-store, skproduct

We have added recently some subscription that contains `SKProductDiscount` of a 6 months and a year.

My question is how to display the right charging value to the user?
In first 6 months the introductory price and after that full price.

Is there other solution rather then calculate?

```
purchaseDate + count * unit > Date()
```

Comment: Did you watch the WWDC video on this topic?

Comment: Hi @matt , yes i have watched the video.